# How to send bot message to all inactive player webhook facebook messenger

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-webhooks

I am new to facebook messenger(Webhook). I am using Nodejs and Heroku for sending bot message. 
   My requirement is to send message to all inactive player at once via 
**Page Access Token**. 
   Is there a way achieve this. Or/ Is there any alternative way.

Thanks

Comment: You could create a node js job on heroku. So the code triggers the Webhook. You can trigger the js file with Heroku Scheduler

Comment: @SimonFranzen, Thanks for reply, Kindly give me some example code or link to proceed.